# SQL insert if last value is different

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

Using SQL Server 2005/2008 I would like to insert a new row if the last value (sorted by `_timestamp`) inserted is not the same value.

For example:

```
value  | timestamp
100    | "yesterday"
101    | "today"
```

For the next operation:

- A value of 101 should not be inserted as this is the latest value

However a value of 102 should be inserted as the latest value is not this

Comment: the last value of what? "value" or "timestamp"?

Comment: Get the top value, and if what you have is different, then do the insert.

Comment: The last value as sorted by timestamp. So in my case the last value is 100.

Comment: I can do 2 SQL actions of selecting the last value (sorted by timestamp desc), comparing and then if different - insert a new record

Comment: To get the last value I use SELECT TOP(1) value FROM table order by _timestamp desc and I have then tried to use CASE WHEN and IF NOT EXISTS

Comment: Please post the code of your attempts to solve this that you mentioned so that we can help debug them.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use something like that?

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(val INT, [timestamp] DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT 100, N'20160112'
UNION ALL
SELECT 101, N'20160113'

SELECT * FROM @table

INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT 101, N'20160114'
WHERE 101 <> ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 val FROM @table
                     ORDER BY timestamp DESC), -1)

SELECT * FROM @table AS T
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciated

Comment: The above example does not work if there is no value in the database so you need to check for is null.